# Append marquee div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have following HTML Structure

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner">123....................</div>
  <div class="inner-1">123....................</div> etc
</div>
```

Now I want to append the following div inside the header div

```
<div style="font-size: small; font-family: helvetica" class="rib">
  <p style="color: #ffffff; background-color: green;">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"
      onmouseover="this.stop();"
      onmouseout="this.start();">My text </marquee>
  </p>
</div>
```

I need JavaScript code, not jquery code. Please help.

Please see my code

```
var ril = document.createElement('div');

ril.setAttribute("class", "ribbon");

ril.innerHTML = "<p style='color: #ffffff; background-color: green;'><marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left' onmouseover='this.stop();' onmouseout='this.start();'>My text </marquee></p>";

document.querySelector(".header").appendChild(ril);

var ril = document.createElement('style');

ril.innerHTML = ".rib{font-size: small; font-family: helvetica;}";
```

Here the code is working, but the problem is **`.rib` div is coming at the ending of .header div ie: `.rib` div is coming after `.inner-1 div`. But I want `.rib` div need to come before the `.inner div`**

Comment: Please see my updated question

Answer (score 1):

1. When you define **htmlString**, use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax by wrapping the whole string with grave accent (```).
2. `.append()` inserts ***after*** the target element content `.prepend()` inserts ***before*** content.
3. A much better method is [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). Its first parameter determines position in relation to target element, and the second parameter is an htmlString to insert and render into real HTML.

   **Example**

   ```
   <div class='target'> TEXT <b>TEXT</b> </div>

   <script>
   /* 
   position can be "beforebegin", "afterbegin", "beforeend", or "afterend"
   (see next sample code)
   */
   const htmlString = `!!!<u>INSERTED HTML</u>!!!`;

   document.querySelector('.target').insertAdjacentHTML(position, htmlString);
   </script>
   ```

   **Position**

   ```
   <!-- "beforebegin" = Externally inserts html before the target -->

   !!!<u>INSERTED HTML</u>!!!<div class='target'> TEXT <b>TEXT</b> </div>

   <!-- "afterbegin" = Internally inserts html before the target content -->

    <div class='target'>!!!<u>INSERTED HTML</u>!!! TEXT <b>TEXT</b> </div>

   <!-- "beforeend" = Internally inserts html after the target content -->

    <div class='target'> TEXT <b>TEXT</b> !!!<u>INSERTED HTML</u>!!!</div>

   <!-- "afterend" = Externally inserts html after the target -->

    <div class='target'> TEXT <b>TEXT</b> </div>!!!<u>INSERTED HTML</u>!!!
   ```

---

#### Demo

```js
const htmlString = `<div style="font-size: small; font-family: helvetica" class="rib">
  <p style="color: #ffffff; background-color: green;"><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">My text </marquee></p>
</div>`;
document.querySelector('.header').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', htmlString);
```

```html
<div class="header">

<div class="inner">123....................</div>
<div class="inner-1">123....................</div> etc
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `.rib` and then insert it into the document using:

```
insertBefore()
```

**Working Example:**

```js
// Create rib
const rib = document.createElement('div');
rib.classList.add('rib');
rib.innerHTML = `
<p class="ribParagraph">
<marquee class="ribMarquee" behavior="scroll" direction="left">My text</marquee>
</p>
`;

// Insert rib into document
const header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];
const inner = document.getElementsByClassName('inner')[0];
header.insertBefore(rib, inner);

// Add Event Listeners to ribMarquee
const ribMarquee = document.getElementsByClassName('ribMarquee')[0];
ribMarquee.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => e.target.stop(), false);
ribMarquee.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => e.target.start(), false);
```

```css
.rib {
  font-size: small;
  font-family: helvetica
}

.ribParagraph {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="inner">123....................</div>
<div class="inner-1">123....................</div>
<header>
```